# Passport local returns error 400 bad request with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am trying to integrate passport to my code's login form. Client side calling server side works as it should until i call passport.authenticate in the request, 400 Bad Request was returned. What am I missing here.

HTML

```
        <div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input id="user-email" type="text" ng-model="user.email">
                    <label for="user-email">Your email address</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input id="user-password" type="password" ng-model="user.password">
                    <label for="user-password">Your password</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="login-button-panel" class="center-align">
                <button class="btn" id="login-btn" ng-click="vm.login(user);">Login</button> 
            </div>
            <div class="section center">
                <a class="modal-trigger">Forgot password?</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS

```
$http.post('/api/login',user).success(function(result){
    console.log(result)
})
```

server.js

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        return done(null, false, {message:'Unable to login'})
    }
));
passport.serializeUser(function(user,done){
    done(null,user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user,done){
    done(null,user);
});
app.post('/api/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req,res){
    res.json(req.user)
});
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**Bad Request** was thrown by passport for missing access on username and password.

It is checking body and URL query for fields `username` and `password`. If either is *falsy* the request is rejected with status 400.

On creating your LocalStrategy you may pass set of options in additional argument to constructor choosing differently named fields using options `usernameField` and/or `passwordField`. In your particular case this would look like this:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    {usernameField:"user-email", passwordField:"user-password"},
    function(username, password, done) {
        return done(null, false, {message:'Unable to login'})
    }
));
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply. And yes you are right. Thanks!

Comment: The options object should be the first argument in the LocalStrategy constructor, not the second argument in the `passport.use` method.

Comment: @Fkids Thanks for the advice. Fixed it.

Comment: Huge help! Thank you sir

Answer (score 14):

In my case (Express 4.0), I wasn't using [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)

Comment: Similarly, I had my `app.use(express.json());` json body parser set after my /login

Answer (score 7):

This error also comes from trying to access the request payload without using **body-parser**

Use -

```
var parser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = parser.urlencoded({extended : false});


    app.post("/authenticate", urlencodedParser, passport.authenticate('local'), function (request, response)
    {           
        response.redirect('/');                      
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    {
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password'
    },
    function (email, password, done) {
        db.collection('User').findOne({ email: email }, async function (err, user) {
            console.log('user requested password caught in passport', password);
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
            const matchPassword = await comparePassword(password, user.password);
            if (!matchPassword) { return done(null, false); }
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
));
```

Comment: Try to explain more clearly why this is an answer to the question.

Comment: by default LocalStrategy takes takes username and password while authenticating from the request but we need is email and password.To make this happen we need  {
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password'
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post("/register",function(req,res){
  Client.register({username:req.body.email},req.body.password,function(err,client){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect("/register")
    }
    else{
      passport.authenticate("local")(req,res,function(){
        console.log("success");
        res.redirect("/secrets")
      })
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Adding `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))` after `app.use(express.json())` solved my problem.