# Authenticating user using passport js

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

According to my scenario, when the user signsup, he will get an SMS where he'll have to enter it to the application. At this point I will consider that the user is authenticated. I am using `passport.js` for this purpose. My code is given below. I have remove the authenticating via SMS code to keep this simple. When the code is executed I get a `400` error message. How can i solve this ?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var csrf = require('csurf');
var passport = require('passport');


var csrfProtection = csrf();
router.use(csrfProtection);


var fs = require('fs');
var ejs = require('ejs');

router.post('/confirmationsignup', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
          user.confirmSignUp(params, function(err, data) {

                 if (err) res.redirect('a/asa');
      });

  });


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: please share what is the field your using for ````username```` and ```password``` - also *refer* this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714202/passport-local-returns-error-400-bad-request-with-angular

Comment: `phoneNum` as the username  and `confirmCode` as the `confirmation code`. This can be considered as the password